# Make Eject key usable in macOS using external USB keyboard on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook

I'm using a MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I have an external USB keyboard connected that has an Eject key. Is there any way I can get this key working and mapped to some other keystroke? I have QuicKeys and Karabiner-Elements installed. But so far, I haven't been able to figure out how to make the Eject key be recognized by the OS when I press it. So even if I could remap it via software, it's as if it just doesn't exist.

```
Hardware Configuration
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,3
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.9 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    4
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 8 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: 185.0.0
  SMC Version (system): 2.45f0

System Software Overview:
  System Version:   macOS 10.12.6 (16G29)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 16.7.0
```

Comment: What model of MacBook Pro?

Comment: I've updated my question with more info on my system.